# Is it possible to connect Azure API Management and Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-ad-b2c

I am designing the architecture of a cloud service. I am reviewing Azure API Management and Azure AD B2C. I can't seem to find any good answer to wether it is possible to use Azure AD B2C with all its features (signup, sign in etc.) as a provider for Azure API Management security - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure API Management supports out of the box integration with Azure AD B2C**.

For instructions on how to integrate Azure AD B2C with the API Management developer portal, check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c).

For instructions on how to validate JWT issued by Azure AD B2C in an API Management policy, check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT).

Note that Azure API Management supports integration with Azure AD and Azure AD B2C in both their Developer and Premium tiers. Check out the [pricing page for more details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management/).

Comment: Hi, the first link exaplains how enable B2C in API Management for developer portal. I've to validate the token JWT (got by Azure B2C) of an API called from a mobile app. So, do I have to follow the second link?  In this case, can I use a APIM Basic plan too?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C integration is supported if you are using the premium tier of API Management service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c

Comment: You should include this link in your answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c

Comment: A quick correction, integration is supported on the Developer tier as well.

Comment: Hi, the first link exaplains how enable B2C in API Management for developer portal. I've to validate the token JWT (got by Azure B2C) of an API called from a mobile app. So, do I have to follow the second link? In this case, can I use a APIM Basic plan too?